# Shortcut to remove current layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shortcuts

I wonder if there is a shortcut / hotkey to remove current layer in QGIS? And if no - is it possible to assign a custom one?

Comment: Ctrl+D is for this action how say @snaileater and you can create new shortcuts,check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pLGvGvhpe0

Comment: Thank you! Could you please submit it as an answer so I can accept it? (and probably add some link to a table with other available shortcuts so others can follow it form your answer?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ctrl+D does the job for me (i think it's a default shortcut) ...

Comment: Command + D (for macs)